# Evaluation of Limit of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k^2+k)/(n^3+n)$

I think this sum is related to riemann sum but I can't see how I convert it into an integration form. Wolfram Alpha fetches the answer to be 1/3.
                Please suggest me a technique to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$  and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{1}^{n} \frac{k^2+k}{n^3+n}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \frac{k^2/n^2+k/n^2}{1+1/n^2}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \frac{k^2}{n^2}=\int_{1}^{1} x^2 dx=\frac{1}{3}.$$
Here we take $x=k/n$ and $k/n^2, 1/n^2 \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Let the numerator be $N_n$. It must be a cubic polynomial in $n$, as the difference $N_n-N_{n-1}=n^2$ is a quadratic polynomial. Hence

$$N_n\sim an^3.$$

From $$n^2+n=N_n-N_{n-1}\sim an^3-a(n-1)^3\sim 3an^2,$$ we conclude $a=\dfrac13$, which is also the requested limit.